# Create select component and want to pass event method out

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have Select.tsx componant

```
import { AdDefinitionInterface } from '../../contexts/adDefinition/AdDefinitionContext';

interface SelectInterface {

  onSelectChange: (value: number | string) => void;
  selectedValue: string | number | undefined;
  ItemData: AdDefinitionInterface[];
}

export default function Select(props: SelectInterface) {
  const { ItemData, onSelectChange, selectedValue } = props;
  return (
    <select value={selectedValue} onChange={(e) => onSelectChange(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="" disabled>
        Select your option
      </option>
      {ItemData.map((def) => (
        <option key={def.adDefinitionId} value={def.adDefinitionId}>
          {def.adDefinitionName} (ID : {def.adDefinitionId})
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

This component use on page and want to update setNewValue for next sumbit on their page

```
  <Select
            selectedValue={selectedAdDefinition?.adDefinitionId}
            onSelectChange= {() => onAdDefinitionChange}
             ItemData={adDefinitions}
  />

  const onAdDefinitionChange = (e: CustomEvent<{ value: number }>) => {
    console.log(e.detail.value)
    const adDefinition = adDefinitions.find((def) => def.adDefinitionId === e.detail.value)!;
    setSelectedAdDefinition(adDefinition);
  };
```

and onAdDefinationChange not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try follow actions:

1. To pass to `onSelectChange={onAdDefinitionChange}` instead `onSelectChange= {() => onAdDefinitionChange}`
2. Note! `onAdDefinitionChange` does not match `onSelectChange`: `((e: CustomEvent<{ value: number }>) => void)` does not match `((value: number | string) => void)`

.

```
import { AdDefinitionInterface } from '../../contexts/adDefinition/AdDefinitionContext';

interface SelectInterface {
  onSelectChange: (value: number | string) => void;
  selectedValue: string | number | undefined;
  ItemData: AdDefinitionInterface[];
}

export default function Select(props: SelectInterface) {
  const { ItemData, onSelectChange, selectedValue } = props;
  return (
    <select value={selectedValue} onChange={(e) => onSelectChange(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="" disabled>
        Select your option
      </option>
      {ItemData.map((def) => (
        <option key={def.adDefinitionId} value={def.adDefinitionId}>
          {def.adDefinitionName} (ID : {def.adDefinitionId})
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

other component

```
<Select
   selectedValue={selectedAdDefinition?.adDefinitionId}
   // was onSelectChange= {() => onAdDefinitionChange}
   // need
   onSelectChange={onAdDefinitionChange}
   ItemData={adDefinitions}
  />

  const onAdDefinitionChange = (e: CustomEvent<{ value: number }>) => {
    console.log(e.detail.value)
    const adDefinition = adDefinitions.find((def) => def.adDefinitionId === e.detail.value)!;
    setSelectedAdDefinition(adDefinition);
  };
```